# Delete all rows from a table with an Entity Framework function using C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, entity-framework

I want to delete all the rows from a table in my SQL Server database (as you can see in the screenshot):

[image]

For that I'm using the following function:

```
private readonly DatabaseContext _context;

[HttpDelete]
public async Task DeleteInstances()
{
    _context.Alertings.RemoveRange();
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

And in the `DbContext` I have this:

```
public class DatabaseContext : DbContext
{
        public DatabaseContext(DbContextOptions<DatabaseContext> options) : base(options)
        {
        }

        public DbSet<AlertingDataModel> Alertings { get; set; }
}
```

And my `AlertingDataModel` is:

```
[Table("Alerting")]
public class AlertingDataModel
{
    [Key]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Instance { get; set; }
    public string Serverity { get; set; }
    public string Summary { get; set; }
    public string State { get; set; }
    public string ActiveAt { get; set; }
}
```

I have done researches, I found this method

```
context.Database.ExecuteSqlCommand("TRUNCATE TABLE [TableName]");
```

But I think it's an old method, I'm using ASP.NET Core 3.1.1.

If someone could help I'll be so thankful :)

Comment: `But I think it's an old method` ← Why? Depending on the number of records in the table you want to empty using a pure EF approach might be just fine but you have to retrieve the records and then delete them. If the table can contain many records then either a DELETE FROM or TRUNCATE TABLE would be preferred.

Comment: I think it's not good using the direct sql execute? That's what I was told, I was looking for a function like the one given by @David

Comment: Raw sql will be more performant but that might not matter at all if the number of records in the table is limited. What you choose should be based on what you need and what you expect the table to contain.

Comment: I'll have a lot of recording cocerning this history of Alerting , now I have to create a BackGround Service that keeps calling the Add method, I think I'll be using a timer of 5mins maybe, I dont know if it's opt and I dont know how to use these background services neither, anyway I'll go read the documentation, thanks for your help :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Raw SQL is the preferred method to perform bulk changes like this.  But the best way to do it otherwise is to fetch all the IDs and construct "Stub Entity" instances with only the IDs populated.

EG

```
var toDelete = db.Alerts.Select(a => new Alert { Id = a.Id }).ToList();
db.Alerts.RemoveRange(toDelete);
db.SaveChanges();
```